# Type script get max array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array with one column n_fnc and I would like to find the max value .
I tried with this but I don"t get anything.

```
 let first = this.fncs.map(item => item.n_fnc);
   console.log("First",first);
    x= Math.max(...first);
```

[[image: max aray]

fnc service

```
getlastid(response,fncs:Fnc[]):void{
      let fnc:Fnc;
      response.forEach(element => {
        
        fnc =new Fnc();
        fnc.n_fnc=element.n_fnc;
        fncs.push(fnc);

    });
```

Fnc component.ts

```
this.fncs=[];
this.fncservice.obs.subscribe((response)=>this.fncservice.getlastid(response,this.fncs));
     console.log("A",this.fncs);
    var max= Math.max.apply(Math, this.fncs.map((m) => m.n_fnc));
    console.log("Max",max);
```

Comment: to get a max of "simple elements": https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max

Comment: This has nothing to do with the finding max. Just for the sake of performance, I recommend using regular for loop to find the max if possible. It seems like you just create another list from original and then reiterate to get the max. The list seems can be quite big imo. Looks like you can get the number relatively easy. Don't be obsessed with those fancy shortcut unless you want to reuse the max list somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` function to do that -

```js
var fncs = [{
 n_fnc: 1
},{
 n_fnc: 499
},{
 n_fnc: 99
},{
 n_fnc: 10
}];

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, fncs.map((m) => m.n_fnc));
console.log(max);
```

The code block in `fnc.component.ts` should be like -

```
this.fncs=[];
this.fncservice.obs.subscribe((response)=> {        
    this.fncservice.getlastid(response,this.fncs);
    console.log("A",this.fncs);
    var max= Math.max.apply(Math, this.fncs.map((m) => m.n_fnc));
    console.log("Max",max);
});
```

Comment: I have fncs table as table of object .
   this.fncs=[];
     this.fncservice.obs.subscribe((response)=>this.fncservice.getlastid(response,this.fncs));

    var max= Math.max.apply(Math, this.fncs.map((m) => m.n_fnc));
I tried this but she return Infinity in max value

Comment: Can you post structure of your array?

Comment: @isawid, you are calling `Math.max.apply` outside of `subscribe`. It should be inside of `subscribe` block.

Comment: How  I would do it ,please?

Comment: @isawid, I have updated my answer with `fnc.component.ts` snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226388/discussion-between-isawid-and-nikhil-patil).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` function to do that -

```js
let fncs = [{
 n_fnc: 1
},{
 n_fnc: 499
},{
 n_fnc: 99
},{
 n_fnc: 10
}];

let mytemp = fncs.sort((a, b) =>  { return b.n_fnc > a.n_fnc ? 1 : -1; });

console.log(mytemp[0]);
```

Comment: error in function(a,b) ... Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.